# Javascript filter dom object by criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a DOM object called lookupTable which holds 5 different objects:

```
0
Object { id=1, version=0, lookup_code="agenda.status", more...}

1
Object { id=2, version=0, lookup_code="agenda.status", more...}

2
Object { id=3, version=0, lookup_code="agenda.status", more...}

3
Object { id=4, version=0, lookup_code="agenda.typ", more...}

4
Object { id=5, version=0, lookup_code="agenda.typ", more...}
```

As you can see there are different lookup_codes in this object and I want to filter those entires with a specific lookup_code, e.g. "agenda.status"

How do I do this?
I tried querySelector, find and filter, but it didn't work...

Thanks in advance,
holgrich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this

```
var newArr = lookupTable.filter(function(x){
   return x.lookup_code == "agenda.status";
});
```

Comment: glad to have helped you :)

Comment: I already had `var r = [];
$.each(lookupTable, function( index, value ){ if( value["lookup_code"]=="agenda.status" ) r.push(value["lookup_code"]);  });
return r;` but that's not performing well :-)